# Change Canvas Value using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am new to javascript and jquery. I am creating Linear gauge using canvas but i want to change data-value using javascript or Jquery. Below code is linear gauge using canvas...  help me to solve this

```
<canvas data-type="linear-gauge"
        id="gauge1"
        data-color-plate="#fff"
        data-color-bar-progress="#0000ff"
        data-width="200"
        data-height="250"
        data-major-ticks="0,300,600,900,1200,1500"
        data-value="600"
        data-min-value="0"
        data-max-value=1500,0
        data-bar-width="50"     
        ></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("canvas").attr("data-value", "YOUR NEW VALUE");
```

you can edit any of your attributes the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```js
$("#gauge1").data("value", "500");
console.log($("#gauge1").data("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<canvas data-type="linear-gauge" id="gauge1" data-color-plate="#fff" data-color-bar-progress="#0000ff" data-width="200" data-height="250" data-major-ticks="0,300,600,900,1200,1500" data-value="600" data-min-value="0" data-max-value=1500,0 data-bar-width="50"></canvas>
```